# How to use if function with multiple range criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I run a macro to copy data from `A5` to `F5` cells from `ABC` sheet to `XYZ` sheet,
but if any cell from `A5` to `F5` are blank i need to get a `msgbox` to update the data in all fields.

i use the below code but getting run time error:

```
Sub Main()

If Range("A5,B5,C5,D5,E5,F5") = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Update data in all fields"
Else 
    MsgBox "Data is appropriate"
End If

End Sub
```

Can anyone suggest me on the same?

Comment: [Avoid implicit references](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/10/25/clean-vba-code-pt-2-avoiding-implicit-code/): Best use [Code Name](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/code-name-sheet1/) to refer to a sheet and [reference Workbooks](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/12/08/document-modules/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a named range and the `CountA` function:

```
Set myRange = Range("A5,B5,C5,D5,E5,F5")
If Application.CountA(myRange) < myRange.Count Then
    MsgBox "Update data in all fields"
Else
    MsgBox "Data is appropriate"
End If
```

This only displays the message box once per attempt.

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.counta
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.count

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do, i'm not an expert maybe is a easy or elegant way.
This is for column check

```
Sub check()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastcolumn As Integer
    lastcolumn = Worksheets("Excel sheet name").Cells(1, Worksheets("Excel sheet name").columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To lastcolumn ' A to F
        If Worksheets("Excel sheet name").Cells(5, i).Value = "" Then
           MsgBox "Update data field: " & i
        Else
           MsgBox "Data is appropriate"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is for row check

```
Sub check()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Worksheets("Excel sheet name").Cells(Worksheets("Excel sheet name").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Worksheets("Excel sheet name").Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
           MsgBox "Update data field: " & i
        Else
           MsgBox "Data is appropriate"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

What you what

```
For i = 1 To 6  'check         
    If Worksheets("YOUR EXCEL SHEET NAME").Cells(5, i).Value = "" Then                                                        
       MsgBox "Update data field: " & i         
    Else            
       'your code       
    End If     
Next i
```

Comment: Getting error on last row = worksheets line and even if i do changes then the msgbox is getting pop-up 6 to 7 times

Comment: Sub Main()

If Range("A5,B5,C5,D5,E5,F5") = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Update data in all fields"
Else 
    MsgBox "Data is appropriate"
End If

End Sub

Comment: i do not want to check any rows or columns just the above cells

Comment: ```For i = 1 To 6  'A to F         If Worksheets("YOUR Excel sheet name").Cells(5, i).Value = "" Then
           MsgBox "Update data field: " & i
        Else
           MsgBox "Data is appropriate"
        End If
    Next i ```

Comment: no it is not working at all, it is just getting msgbox pop-up for 7 times

Comment: i'm asking to check if not display only one msgbox not 7 times

Comment: that means the cells are blank, Paste your new code, the new one that gives msgbox

Answer (score 0):

To check for an empty cell, you have too loop through the cells. Using `Exit For` you can stop the loop when you want it to:

```
Dim c
For Each c In Array("A5", "B5", "C5", "D5", "E5", "F5")
   If Range(c) = Empty Then
    MsgBox "One of the cells is Empty"
    Exit For
   End If
Next
```

Comment: thanks a lot but there is one more thing i need to know. the above vba says if cell is empty then i need else to call another macro

Comment: You need a boolean var e.g. `isEmpty`set to false on top of code and sst to true in if block. Then you can check at end of code wether it is true (there was an empty cell in range) or false (range was filled). But stay with JMP solution, that should be faster.